# How to add a value in the y-axis at the bottom of a bar chart-css

Tags: html, css

I'm using this as my exercise code work: **[CodePen](http://codepen.io/tsensuous/pen/jrPBxB)**

I want to add $0 at the bottom of the bar chart in the y-axis. i/e instead of starting from $10,0000 I want to start from $0. Is there any way to do that in CSS?

HTML for y-axis:

```
<div id="ticks">
<div class="tick" style="height: 59px;"><p>$50,000</p></div>
<div class="tick" style="height: 59px;"><p>$40,000</p></div>
<div class="tick" style="height: 59px;"><p>$30,000</p></div>
<div class="tick" style="height: 59px;"><p>$20,000</p></div>
<div class="tick" style="height: 59px;"><p>$10,000</p></div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another `.tick` with the $0 value, and assign the border to the top instead of the bottom. Then, give your `#ticks` a bottom border.

**CSS**

```
#ticks .tick {
  border-top: 1px solid #C4C4C4; */ Change to top /*
}

#ticks {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #C4C4C4; */ Add bottom border /*
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="ticks">
  <div class="tick" style="height: 59px;"><p>$50,000</p></div>
  <div class="tick" style="height: 59px;"><p>$40,000</p></div>
  <div class="tick" style="height: 59px;"><p>$30,000</p></div>
  <div class="tick" style="height: 59px;"><p>$20,000</p></div>
  <div class="tick" style="height: 59px;"><p>$10,000</p></div>
  <div class="tick" style="height: 59px;"><p>$0</p></div>
</div>
```

**[CodePen](http://codepen.io/Hunter377/pen/QKbpov)**

---

**EDIT CSS Only**

If you do not have access to the HTML and would like to achieve this in CSS only, you can use something like `:before`.

**CSS**

```
#ticks .tick:last-child:before {
  content: '$0';
  position: absolute;
  left: -5em; 
  bottom: -5px;
  margin: 0 0 0 0.5em;
}
```

**[CodePen](http://codepen.io/Hunter377/pen/PGqmYz)**

---

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked how to do this in CSS rather than adding another html element, here is a way to do it using the CSS3 pseudo :after element. You may want to adjust the right and top properties as you see fit.

```
#q1:after {
   content:"$0";
   position:relative;
   color:#000;
   right:85px;
   top:285px;
 }
```